# Hide Specific label posts from homepage in blogger

Tags: html, blogger

I have a website for [Best Whatsapp Status](http://www.whatsappstatus.co) on blogger blog . I want to hide some specific label posts from the homepage . Is there anyway to do that with coding.
I have searched a lot but nothing worked for me . Please help anyone

Answer (score 0):

Go to your template editor, then find the code below: (Please BACKUP your template first)

```
<b:if cond='data:post.dateHeader'>
    <h2 class='date-header'><data:post.dateHeader/></h2>
</b:if>
<b:include data='post' name='post'/>
```

If you can't find the code, just find that similiar to that. Replace that code with this code:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
<b:if cond='data:post.labels == &amp;quot;&amp;quot;'>
<b:if cond='data:post.dateHeader'>
<h2 class='date-header'><data:post.dateHeader/></h2>
</b:if>
<b:include data='post' name='post'/>
</b:if>
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
<b:if cond='data:label.isLast'>
<b:if cond='data:label.name != &amp;quot;LABEL NAME&amp;quot;'>
<b:if cond='data:post.dateHeader'>
<h2 class='date-header'><data:post.dateHeader/></h2>
</b:if>
<b:include data='post' name='post'/>
</b:if>
</b:if>
</b:loop>
<b:else/>
<b:if cond='data:post.dateHeader'>
<h2 class='date-header'><data:post.dateHeader/></h2>
</b:if>
<b:include data='post' name='post'/>
</b:if>
```

Replace `LABEL NAME` with the label name that you want to hide from homepage. It may be case sensitive!

Comment: <b:if cond='data:post.dateHeader'>
    <h2 class='date-header'><data:post.dateHeader/></h2>
</b:if>

this lines are present in my code but the fourth line is not present .  (ie. <b:include data='post' name='post'/>  )

and i have replaced these three lines with this code and replaced the label name with my label name which i want to hide , but it didn't worked . 
is there any other way to do this with coding .

Comment: can you find `<b:include data='post' name='post'/>` in your template?

Comment: can you please show your template code? you may paste it in pastebin.

Comment: I have the same, the first 3 lines, are in 3 different places but the last <b:include data='post' name='post'/> its only once and not after the first 3 lines

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote about that in my blog, using a little bit of a different approach, with javascript.
Maybe this'll work for you:

http://bekreatief.blogspot.com/2014/07/blogger-take-certain-post-out-of-stream.html